# Error al activar Oracle Flashback

Tags: oracle, oracle-10g, flashback

Estoy tratando de habilitar `Oracle Flashback` en una base de datos Oracle 10g que tengo montada en una máquina virtual ( que tiene Windows XP ).

Este es mi script:

```
--chechar si estan habilitados los respaldos flashback
SELECT FLASHBACK_ON FROM V$DATABASE;
-- sale YES o NO

--poner tamaño de respaldos a 9 gigas
ALTER SYSTEM SET DB_RECOVERY_FILE_DEST_SIZE = 9G SCOPE=BOTH;

--lugar donde se van a guardar los respaldos
ALTER SYSTEM SET DB_RECOVERY_FILE_DEST = 'C:/oracle/flash_recovery_area';

--hacer que los respaldos duren dos días
ALTER SYSTEM SET DB_FLASHBACK_RETENTION_TARGET = 2880; /* 2 Dias */

--habilitar
ALTER DATABASE FLASHBACK ON;
```

En la última línea obtengo el error

> ORA-38759: La base de datos debe estar montada por una sola instancia y no estar abierta.

SSale incluso si reinicio el servicio.

¿Qué debo hacer para solucionarlo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Listo, ya pude corregirlo.

Deben correr los comandos siempre en sqlplus.

Para apagar la base:

```
shutdown immediate;
```

para montarla sin abrirla

```
startup mount;
```

Si aquí al correr el comando

```
ALTER DATABASE FLASHBACK ON;
```

les manda error

> ora-38707: La recuperación del medio físico no está activada

Aplicar adicionalmente

```
alter database archivelog;
```

Para verificar que se haya cambiado correr la consulta

```
select flashback_on from v$database;
```

deberían de obtener una salida que diga

```
FLASHBACK_ON
------------------
YES
```

finalmente no olvidar reabrir la base con

```
alter database open;
```